# Define a function given some constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I try to define a two-variable function $f(x,y) \ge 0$ with both $x,y \in [0,1]$ which satisfies the following constraints:

1. $f$ is increasing in both $x$ and $y$
2. if $x=0$ then $f(x,y)=0$
3. if $y=0$ then $f(x,y)=0$ only if $x=0$

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would the function $f(x,y)=x(y+1)$ work?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to not to involve some arbitrary constant $\alpha \gt 0$ (such as $\alpha = 1$ here)? The inconvenience is that I have to justify for the particular choice of $\alpha$ here.

Comment: @skyork: $f(x,y)=x\cdot g(y)$ should work for any function $g$ that is increasing on $[0,1]$ with $g(0)>0$.  I'm not sure that any particular choice of $g$ is any less arbitrary that $g(y)=y+1$, though.

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x,y) = xe^y$? No arbitrary constant as required!