# Find a function given constraints?

Tags: polynomials, constraints, constraint-programming

There are similar questions:

[Finding 'closest' function subject to constraints on derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735504/finding-closest-function-subject-to-constraints-on-derivatives)

[Define a function given some constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110987/define-a-function-given-some-constraints)

[Find a function given its poles, residues, limit at infinity, and additional constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976398/find-a-function-given-its-poles-residues-limit-at-infinity-and-additional-con)

but maybe this is more general.

Can one find a function given first order logic type constraints on the domain and range values, and even some range values (but not polynomial interpolation with just set of mappings) for example, say our mystery function is:

```
f(x) = x^2 + 1
```

But all we have are a set of constraints like:

```
forall x, f(x) < f(x+1)
forall x, f(x) < 2 * f(x+1)
f(1) = 2
f(10) = 101
```

Is it possible to produce a function (or functions) that satisfies the given constraints through some mathematical process or computation? What area of math is this?